# Log transformed response variable and overfitting issues in random forest regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn, overfitting

I am trying to fit random forest regression for continuous skewed response variable with so many zeros. Here is the plot of the response variable:

[image]

In [An Introduction
to Statistical
Learning](https://www.statlearning.com/), authors used log transformed salary to fit regression trees so that its distribution has more of a typical bell-shape. How does this log transformation of response variable work in random forest regression? I see some conflicting suggestions are available online! I have got the following results so far without log transformed response variable using Python `sklearn` framework:

```
MAE train: 4.07
MAE test: 12.25
MSE train: 26.46
MSE test: 231.33
R^2 train: 0.96
R^2 test: 0.68
```

Sample data: (Sample size 179)

[image]
I see that the above results have issues with the overfitting although I knew that random forest regression doesn't suffer from overfitting. Not sure what happened here! I appreciate your suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide your model's best hyperparameters and some information about your data. Also, is your response a natural number or real value?

Comment: @SanjarAdylov Response is a continuous float variable. Here is the model info: RandomForestRegressor(criterion='absolute_error', max_depth=10,
                      max_features='sqrt', random_state=47)

Comment: I believe `max_depth=10` is too deep even for a random forest being trained on 179 samples and 18 features. Try smaller values and report your findings. Same with `n_estimators`.

Comment: @SanjarAdylov I got these values from 5-fold Gridsearch CV.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting... If you believe that the parameter grid in `GridSearchCV` was comprehensive enough so that you got the best parameters, then how about exploring a single `DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='absolute_error', max_features=None)` instead of ensembles? Try training `DecisionTreeRegressor` and plotting it with `plot_tree`. You will overfit and see what are the maximum depth and impurity paths. And according to these observation, you can further control the complexity of your trees with `min_impurity_decrease` and/or `ccp_alpha`, if tuning `max_depth` didn't help.

Comment: @SanjarAdylov How abt the log transformation of the response variable like OLS regression?